# Derivation of magnetic field caused by a current carrying wire

Tags: magnetic-fields

When we derive the equation of a magnetic field produced by a long straight current-carrying wire, we do something like this:

> Imagine a wire carrying a constant current $I$. Take a point at a distance of $r$ from the wire, this is the point where we want to find the magnetic field. So, draw a circle with radius $r$ and center at the wire (from which the point's distance is $r$). Applying the **Ampere's Law** $$ \oint \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = \mu_{0} ~I$$
>
> [image]
>
> Since the magnitude of $\mathbf{B}$ is constant at every line element of the loop (circle) and it dot product with the line element is $B~dl$ everywhere, therefore $$ \oint B~dl = \mu_0 ~I$$
> $$ B~\oint dl = \mu_0 ~I$$
> $$ B~ 2\pi r = \mu_0 ~I $$
> $$ B = \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi r} ~I $$

Now, the problem is how do we know that the magnitude of **B** is going to be constant and its direction will be the same as a line element. I think it's this assumption that has really solved the problem and not the *mathematics* . Is it an experimental fact? How can we ever made such an assumption when the only thing that we have is *Elcetrostatics* (I mean that *electrostatics* was the precursor of *magnetostatics* and *magnetostatics* always takes the analogy of static charges in *electrostatics*) where the field varies with distance.

I want to state my problem once more: **How do we know that magnetic field's strength gonna be constant all around the loop and always tangential to the loop?** .

Thank you. Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Following @Dale answer, we can do something like this
$$ d\mathbf{B} = \mu_0 /4\pi ~ I ~ \frac {d\mathbf{l} \times \mathbf{r}} {r^3} $$
Since, **r** can be written as $ \mathbf{r} = (rcos\theta, rsin\theta , z) $ and d**l** as $ d\mathbf{l} = ( dl,0,0) $
And now, if we take the cross product we would get $$ d\mathbf{l} \times \mathbf{r} = -z ~dl \hat j + rsin\theta \hat k$$ and therefore the magnitude of d**B** is equal to $$ dB = \mu_0/4\pi ~I~ |d\mathbf{l} \times \mathbf{r}| /r^3 = \mu_0/4\pi ~I ~ \sqrt{z^2+r^2sin^2\theta} dl/ r^3 $$

Thus, magnetic field is depending on $r, \theta, z$ . Please help.

Comment: Wire is along the z direction. So d**l** = (0, 0, d**l**)

Comment: @aditya_stack Okay, but it doesn't make any difference if we take the wire in $x$ direction or $z$ direction, all it gonna change is to swap the components in cross product.

Comment: It will make a difference. Notice that the loop is always going **around** the wire. So if you take the wire in x direction so that d**l** = (dl, 0, 0) then to apply Ampere's Law correctly you must also change **r** to be **r** = (x, rcos$\theta$, rsin$\theta$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do we know that the magnitude of B is going to be constant and its direction will be the same as a line element

We know that the magnitude is constant by symmetry. Since there is cylindrical symmetry (axisymmetric) the magnitude can only depend on $r$, and therefore cannot depend on $\theta$ or on $z$.

For the direction, that is a little more complicated. If we break $\vec B$ into $\hat r$, $\hat \theta$, and $\hat z$ components, then we see that the $\hat z$ component must be zero because the Biot Savart law requires $\vec B$ to be perpendicular to $\vec I$. If the $\hat r$ component were nonzero then we would have a nonzero divergence which would violate Gauss’ law for magnetism. So only the $\hat \theta$ component can be nonzero. And its magnitude is determined by the integral you posted.

Comment: Coincidentally, I was writing an answer with the same argument as yours. But, why should the $\hat{z}$ component be zero by symmetry? The direction of the current brings an asymmetry in that direction.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that. The current is a vector not a scalar. I need to fix that part. The rest should be good. Hold on

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer just a little? Your answer has really helped me but I'm getting some problems please see my edit.

Comment: @Knight I think you are mixing up $d\vec l$ and $d\vec I$. $d\vec I$ is a differential element of current in the straight wire. $d\vec l$ is a differential length of the loop of wire. Or alternatively (depending on your notation) there are two different $d\vec l$ one for the wire and one for the loop.

Comment: In my edit i used $dl$ with your meaning of $dI$. I used $dl$ as the element of current carrying wire not the Amperean loop.

Comment: @Knight The $\mathbf{r}$ in Biot Savart law is the vector whose tail is at the infinitesimal piece of wire $dl$ and whose head is at the point you want to calculate the magnetic field. When you wrote $\mathbf{r}=(r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z)$, this is just the position vector whose tail is at the origin of the coordinate system and whose head is at the point you want to calculate the magnetic field.

Comment: @Knight Does [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/ni9scU5dGu34NYvm9) picture from Google images help?

Comment: @AjayMohan Wow, thank you. I never realized that thing of Biot-Savart Law. Does it mean that when we integrate to get total field we keep on changing the origin? Your comment can make me to learn a lot.

Comment: No, keep the origin fixed. First, we find the cross product $d\mathbf{l} \times \mathbf{r}$ for each infinitesimal segment of the wire. And then we are just adding each of these infinitesimal vectors by performing this integration: $\int d\mathbf{l} \times \mathbf{r}$. In short, each infinitesimal segment gives you a vector and you just add all of these vectors by performing the integration.

Comment: @Knight As an example, let's say we have a circular loop of current-carrying wire of radius $b$ (current flowing counter clockwise when viewed from +z axis) and we want to find the magnetic field at the centre of the loop. Let the origin be placed there. Now, each infinitesimal segment of the wire gives the vector $d\mathbf{l} \times \mathbf{r} =  dl \;b \hat{z}$. Now, we are just adding these infinitesimal vectors by performing the integration: $\int dl\; b \hat{z} = (\int dl) b \hat{z}= l b \hat{z} = 2 \pi b^2 \hat{z}$.